# How to compress before encrypting message in a custom binding?

Tags: wcf, encryption, compression, wshttpbinding, custom-binding

I have followed the example at microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx regarding creation of a custom binding to compress messages. However, I want to have my traffic encrypted at the same time. This works great, however the encryption is performed before my compression, meaning that the size of the message is becoming larger instead of smaller...
My binding is configured as

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="GZipBinding" >                 
    <gzipMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding"/>
    <transactionFlow />
    <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" >
      <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="UserNameForCertificate" />
    </security>                 
    <httpTransport  maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" maxBufferSize="104857600"/>
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Is it possible somehow to compress before I encrypt the message ?

Answer (score 0):

DON'T do this.  Compressing  data in an encrypted stream causes a security vulnerability. If an attacker can effect the contents of the message being encrypted, they can use the compression of repeated data to read the contents of the encrypted file. You can see the details of such an attack [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19914/9451) as it showed up in SSL recently.

Comment: Interesting... But what if one wants to get the inner message compacted somehow to reduce data transferred, what would one do then ?